# Read text file, split it, then show it in listBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, openfiledialog

I need to read a text file containing time stamps and temperatures. The thing is, I need to only show the temperatures in a listBox, spliting the string before displaying it.
So far I've managed to show the text file in the list, but im struggling with removing the timestamps.

My code:

```
     public partial class Form1 : Form           
     {
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
        string line = "";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFile.FileName);
                while(line != null)
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if(line != null)
                    {
                        string[] newLine = line.Split(' ');
                        listBox1.Items.Add(newLine);
                    }
                }
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
```

Now the listBox only shows String[] array.
Oh, and also I need to include this in my code:

```
const int numOfTemp = 50;
double dailyTemp[numOfTemps];
```

The textfile is in this format:
11:11:11 -10,50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take `[1]` item of the the array after `Split`:

```
    using System.Linq;

    ...

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFile.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
          return;

        var temps = File
          .ReadLines(openFile.FileName)
          .Select(line => line.Split(' ')[1]); // we need temperature only

        try {
          listBox1.BeginUpdate();

          // In case you want to clear previous items
          // listBox1.Items.Clear();

          foreach (string temp in temps) 
             listBox1.Items.Add(temp);
        }
        finally {
          listBox1.EndUpdate();
        } 
    }
```